# Setting UART word length on Beaglebone Black (Python)

Tags: python, serial-port, beagleboneblack

I'm using Python on my Beaglebone Black to configure a couple of UARTs. I can't find any tutorials or documentation to tell me how to set the UART for 9 bit word length.

Specs:

- Debian GNU/Linux 7.4 (wheezy)
- Python ver 2.7.3
- Adafruit Library

Sample code:

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.UART as UART
import serial


UART.setup("UART1")
ser1=serial.Serial(port="/dev/ttyO1", bits=9, baudrate=19200)
```

Python tells me "bits" is an unexpected argument. I saw this format in an online tutoral as well as a method called `any()` to see if a character is waiting in the UART, but these don't seem to work.

Comment: I think the problem you're having has to do with the `serial` module, which I assume is PySerial whose [documentation](http://pyserial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyserial.html) I'm looking at. Try using `bytesize=9` instead of `bits=9`.

Comment: OK, I see in the documentation that 9 bits is not supported. Only 5-8 bits. Thanks.

Comment: Too bad, because the [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver/transmitter#Data_framing) is 5-9 bits.